# double , long in Java use

Tags: java, android

> double ps1 = (double) (((double)1)/(double)100);
>                           int maz = (double) ((ps1) * Double.parseDouble(500000.102)));

Is this right to use double, or shall i use long?
I am doing large calculations. And need to keep the correctness of the .102.

Comment: It obviously has to be double, since long has no fractional part.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here - are all those numbers really literals in your code? Why are you calling `Double.parseDouble()` in the second line on something that already is a `double` and not a `String`? Why do you cast to `double` if you then immediately assign to `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double! Because `long` has no signs after `,` (they have no fraction)